# If we enable data logging on a google-cloud-speech enabled project do we get to access the audio files along with their recognition metadata?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-speech

We want to use google-cloud-speech to perform streaming speech-to-text conversion. If we enable data logging, will the audio data and the recognition metadata be saved in bucket associated with project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and in fact, it's typically the other way around.  You can upload your audio file to a Cloud Storage bucket, and the Speech API can read directly from that using a gs:// URL that you provide.

According to the documentation, [Data logging](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/data-logging) just is for allowing Google to improve its models using the data you provide.  It's not for remembering everything you ever did with the API.